# Change text color while typing in angular

Tags: angular

I am working on a Note Taking application, Requirement is when user types the text, It should in Red color, If he wants the rest of the text to be in black color while typing that also has to be achieved

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am so confused on ver to start

Comment: Have a look at `ngClass` and `ngStyle`. Those are built in directives that allow you to change styles/classes programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<input type="text" (focus)="isFocused = true" (blur)="isFocused = false" [style.color]="isFocused ? 'red':'black'">
```

TS:

```
isFocused:boolean
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked, Is it possible to make a particular text in red when clicking on a button and the rest all text in black.

Comment: You can post a new question with whatever you have tried